# Change component value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently building a weather web app with React, and now I have a question: How do I change my components (SaveWeather) city-value?

Say that you clicked on a button where you entered 'Berlin', and the code below runs. The `this.state.value` is 'Berlin', and I want to add SaveWeather component with this value. But if I enter my next value, say 'London', The `this.state.value` is still 'Berlin'. So I want to update the city-value of SaveWeather every time the user enters new information.

```
test() {
  this.setState({
    saveWeather: [this.state.saveWeather, <SaveWeather city={this.state.value} key="1" />]
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share with us a codesandbox with full code?

Comment: I imagine you want to update your state before you actually pass its' value into component

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really save components in your state, only data. The way I'd do this would be something like this.

Your state:

```
{value: "Initial Value that can be an empty string"}
```

A function that handles the value changes:

```
handleValueChange(e) {
  // e is the event that comes from the input element (where the user writes the city they want)
  const city =  e.target.value;
  this.setState({value: city})
}
```

Then, in your render:

```
render() {
  return <div>
    <input onChange={this.handleValueChange} value={this.state.value}/>
    <SaveWeather city={this.state.value} />
  </div>
}
```

You should try to understand this code, don't just copy it. Any question drop a comment below ;)